# image overlapping edittext while typing

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I have an edittext and below to that imageview followed by 3 textviews. when i try to type in the edittext the 3 textview are displaying properly. But when i add the image and try typing in the edittext the image is displaying on top of edittext means image is overlapping the edittext.

XML:

```
<ScrollView
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:fillViewport="true"
  android:background="#ffffffff">



<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".Main"
    android:paddingStart="5dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/userDisplay"
        android:text="Username"
        android:textColor="#ff6aa9ff"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/FName"
        android:hint="FName"
        android:background="#ffffffff"
        android:gravity="start|left"
        android:inputType="textFilter|textMultiLine"
        android:maxLength="150"

        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/userDisplay" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="Camera"
        android:id="@+id/Camera"
        android:paddingTop="7dp"
        android:paddingBottom="7dp"
        android:background="#ffffffff"
        android:textSize="21sp"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/compact"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="Gallery"
        android:id="@+id/Gallery"
        android:paddingTop="7dp"
        android:paddingBottom="7dp"
        android:paddingLeft="7dp"
        android:background="#ffffffff"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/gallery"
        android:textSize="21sp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/Camera"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Camera" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text=" Post"
        android:id="@+id/Post"
        android:paddingTop="7dp"
        android:paddingBottom="7dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:background="#ffff5654"
        android:textSize="21sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#ff000000"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/plane"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/Gallery"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Gallery" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="180dp"
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:contentDescription="@string/abc_action_bar_home_description"
        android:layout_marginBottom="76dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />


</RelativeLayout>
 </ScrollView>
```

and in the Android manifest file i do mention the below line the activity. Tried by removing the below line but same behavior is seen.

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize"
```

What changes can i do to avoid this

Comment: You have `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"` in both EditText and ImageView. Is this causing the issue?

Comment: Removed those lines and tested. Same behavior.

Comment: Try
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"

Answer (score 1):

if you want that you'r image will be "under" your edittext ,put the image in First position

like

```
RelativeLayout  
 ImageView  
 EditText 
 EditText
 EditText
RelativeLayout
```

after if you want that everything has the same moove put everthing inside a LinearLayout like

```
   RelativeLayout 
     ImageView  
    LinearLayout 
     EditText 
     EditText
     EditText
    LinearLayout 
   RelativeLayout
```

something like that

Answer (score 0):

Use `LinearLayout` with `orientation="vertical"` if you dont want to overlap image and texts ..

or

If you want to overlap TextViews and Edittext over Image try to put Imageview in Beginning of Relative layout or set it in background of RelativeLayout .